# Asynchronous prompt_toolkit for user input in twisted

Tags: python, twisted, prompt-toolkit

I am trying to write a simple command line client as a wrapper for a TCP client/server system. The client is written in python using the `twisted` framework. I am using Python3.6 as the interpretor. I found that `prompt_toolkit` has an `asyncio` implementation and attempted to use the example code to connect it into a twisted system using `ensureDeferred`. Unfortunately, the code throws an exception as soon as the prompt is displayed.

I am new to using asyncio library tools in python, so I am not sure if I am missing something. The code that I attempted to run is the following:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import ensureDeferred
from prompt_toolkit import prompt_async


async def my_coroutine():
    while True:
        result = await prompt_async('Say something: ', patch_stdout=True)
        print('You said: %s' % result)


d = ensureDeferred(my_coroutine())
reactor.run()
```

The exception that is thrown is the following:

```
 AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

I am not sure if this is a fundamental incompatibility between twisted and asyncio or if I am missing a key way to connect these two systems. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Version Details:

```
twisted == 17.9.0
prompt_toolkit == 1.0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is install the `asyncioreactor` so that Twisted's native event loop works in parallel with the `asyncio` event loop.

```
import twisted.internet.asyncioreactor
twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.install()
# add your imports + code here
```

I'm not sure how ready the `asyncioreactor` is for production use, which may be the reason why there isn't much in terms of documentation.

## Resources

- https://gist.github.com/ldjebran/4febf298232a6fd86871df25d4dc00dd
- https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/9279
- https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/ed075dad7339456c47fe43a51a12ee4b5910e0fd/src/twisted/internet/asyncioreactor.py

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not aware of the reactor. I attempted to run with this reactor installed on a Linux system and OSX without success. I will investigate further, but this was a very helpful starting place.